# Create a Timer like Time.time but with possibility to reset it to 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

can i make a timer or reset somehow Time.time ? i tried making this

```
    float Timer(float time)
    {
        if (Time.time > nextTime)
        {
            return 0.01f;
            nextTime = Time.time + 0.01f;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

but it seems it not work properly, time don't count same as Time.time

Comment: `Time.time` is the number of seconds that have passed since the game was started. It's not something you should be looking to reset. Create your own float variable and increment it on `Update` loops by `Time.deltaTime`, and reset that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create timer like this

```
  public float timeLeft=5f;

     void FixedUpdate()
     {
         timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
         if(timeLeft < 0)
         {
             DoSomething();
             timeLeft=5f; //If you want to reset timer 
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static float _lastTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;

    [SerializeField, Tooltip("Time in second between timer ding dong."), Range(0f, 3600f)]
    private float _interval = 5f;

    public UnityEvent OnTickTack;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Time.realtimeSinceStartup - _lastTime >= _interval)
        {
            _lastTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
            OnTickTack.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could always use coroutine "yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);"

Comment: timer can't be reseted to 0. it just being set same as Time.time